# HttpClient certificate when hosted in IIS/Asp.NET Application not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpclient, x509certificate

I have a strange problem.
I need to perform an SSL request using a CER client certificate, to a server that requires authentication by that certificate.

I am using the code below:

```cs
   var cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("cert.cer");

   var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
   handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

   var http_client = new HttpClient(handler);
   http_client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://service.com/");

   var str_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
   {
       Field = "Value1",
       Fiesl2 = "Value2"
   });

   var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str_json));
   byteContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
   byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

   var res = http_client.PostAsync("ResourcePath", byteContent).Result;

   res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //THe error 401 ocurrs here

   var res_body = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This code works perfectly when I squeeze into a ConsoleApplicaiton or a WebApplication in IIS Express.

But when I squeeze exactly the same code in Local IIS or IIS Server, I get the 401-Unauthorized error. The strange thing is that using Fiddler, in this case I can not even see the request attempt.

I've already checked that path is not the problem.
The problem occours in .NET 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1 and etc..

Can anyone help me out, is it any configuration that should be performed in IIS. I've researched a lot, but I did not find that specific error.

Comment: A `.cer` file at client side does not contain private key, so usually it won't work if mutual SSL/TLS is required by the server. Nobody else but the server administrators can tell you more about it and then you need to get a valid certificate with private key (usually a `.pfx` file).

Comment: @LexLi is correct, you are using client certificate without private key.

Comment: You are correct, using the one .pfx with PrivateKey works in all situations. Thank you, you saved my life. @LexLi can you post a response to mark as solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.cer` file at client side does not contain private key, so usually it won't work if mutual SSL/TLS is required by the server. You need to get a valid certificate with private key (usually a `.pfx` file).